# What software can i use to analyze logs from log4j

Tags: java, data-analysis, logs, log-analysis

I have a bunch of log files

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-132:~/queue/logs$ ls -la
total 492296
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root       4096 Feb  4 16:29 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 ubuntu ubuntu     4096 Jan 25 22:25 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485766 Jan 25 22:29 queue-2021-01-25_1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485954 Jan 25 22:34 queue-2021-01-25_2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485932 Jan 25 22:43 queue-2021-01-25_3.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485855 Jan 25 23:42 queue-2021-01-25_4.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485921 Jan 25 23:48 queue-2021-01-25_5.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485782 Jan 26 01:06 queue-2021-01-26_1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485916 Jan 26 07:51 queue-2021-01-26_10.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10488038 Jan 26 08:32 queue-2021-01-26_11.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10486093 Jan 26 08:48 queue-2021-01-26_12.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10486173 Jan 26 09:12 queue-2021-01-26_13.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485893 Jan 26 09:51 queue-2021-01-26_14.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485775 Jan 26 10:15 queue-2021-01-26_15.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485981 Jan 26 10:32 queue-2021-01-26_16.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485855 Jan 26 10:45 queue-2021-01-26_17.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485887 Jan 26 15:41 queue-2021-01-26_18.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10486126 Jan 26 17:33 queue-2021-01-26_19.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10486766 Jan 26 01:19 queue-2021-01-26_2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485776 Jan 26 17:54 queue-2021-01-26_20.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485862 Jan 26 19:43 queue-2021-01-26_21.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485790 Jan 26 20:59 queue-2021-01-26_22.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485879 Jan 26 21:17 queue-2021-01-26_23.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485823 Jan 26 21:37 queue-2021-01-26_24.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485846 Jan 26 01:38 queue-2021-01-26_3.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10486070 Jan 26 01:47 queue-2021-01-26_4.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485770 Jan 26 01:57 queue-2021-01-26_5.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485797 Jan 26 07:01 queue-2021-01-26_6.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485763 Jan 26 07:07 queue-2021-01-26_7.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485933 Jan 26 07:21 queue-2021-01-26_8.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485941 Jan 26 07:49 queue-2021-01-26_9.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485820 Jan 27 10:09 queue-2021-01-27_1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10486724 Jan 27 11:57 queue-2021-01-27_2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10486293 Jan 27 13:09 queue-2021-01-27_3.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10486700 Jan 27 20:10 queue-2021-01-27_4.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485852 Jan 27 22:03 queue-2021-01-27_5.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485780 Jan 28 07:12 queue-2021-01-28_1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10488404 Jan 28 07:16 queue-2021-01-28_2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485918 Jan 28 08:11 queue-2021-01-28_3.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10486544 Jan 28 08:15 queue-2021-01-28_4.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485862 Jan 28 10:18 queue-2021-01-28_5.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10486964 Feb  1 11:44 queue-2021-02-01_1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485876 Feb  2 09:42 queue-2021-02-02_1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485875 Feb  2 09:52 queue-2021-02-02_2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485899 Feb  2 10:04 queue-2021-02-02_3.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485906 Feb  2 10:47 queue-2021-02-02_4.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485853 Feb  3 02:31 queue-2021-02-03_1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485889 Feb  3 13:05 queue-2021-02-03_2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485846 Feb  3 16:27 queue-2021-02-03_3.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   10485873 Feb  4 16:29 queue-2021-02-04_1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     578921 Feb  4 16:35 queue.log
```

created using `log4j2` loggin framework for java, each log event in format:

`time` [`thread name`] `level` `source` - `message`

for example:
`16:29:12.374 [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed`

As raw log files are hard to work with, i'm looking for some software to join the log files together and let me analyze logs effectively.

Some requirements:

- Must run on Ubuntu 24.04LTS 64Bit
- Preferably free
- An option to filter the events based on `level`
- An option to filter the events from source with an option for inheritance, for example if i select source `com.example` i want to see logs from `com.example.something` too, but not `com.somethingelse`